# Replaced /\t/ with / / on git repo

Tags: git, repository

Was up too late last night working on some legacy code I inherited from someone else. In addition to putting the thing under revision control, I wanted to convert the codebase away from tabs to spaces. Ended up replacing all tab characters with two spaces in my working directory. Recursively. Including the .git directory. I had made some changes and committed them, but hadn't pushed the repo anywhere else yet.

It's not a huge loss if I just have to start the repo over again and squash changes so far into one commit, but supposing I was to put in the effort, how recoverable is this situation?

In a way I'm glad I made this mistake before I got too far in, but suppose it was the only copy of a years-long project, how screwed would you be?

Comment: The main trickiness is that there's now no easy way to tell what was originally two spaces and what was originally a tab. You're probably off just re-creating the repository. (Hopefully in the case of a years-long project there'd be another remote somewhere that you could re-clone from.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Recursively. Including the .git directory
> First you need to verify that your `.git` folder is not "broken".

```
# Verify that the .git folder and all the objects are still usable
git fsck --full
```

If you don't see and dangling data you are OK.

> but hadn't pushed the repo anywhere else yet

You could still recover all the previous data even if you pushed (unless you did a forced push)

---

> In a way I'm glad I made this mistake before I got too far in, but suppose it was the only copy of a years-long project, how screwed would you be?

If you don't have backup you will be in a HUGE trouble. its a recoverable situation but it will require a lot of work.

---

#### How to recover from this error?

If you have replaced all the tabs to spaces or vice versa you will have to try and replace them again, the good thing is that git has the SHA-1 which is the [***`sha1sum`***](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_sha1sum.htm) of the content (the content itself is zipped and the format inside should not contain any spaces.

Is short (its a bit more complicated than this) git calculate the SHA-1 of the following content and compress it :

```
blob<space><content_lengt><null><content>
```

Then git compress the above content with zlib. So if you know how files are stored you can try to recover them buts its a lot of work. On the other hand there shouldn't be spaces in the content so the odds that you would have messed something inside (`.git/object`) is small.

### ***`Summary`***

Does not matter what you do ***never*** touch the `.git` folder !!!

---

[image]

Comment: So it'd probably be some kind of process whereby you'd be trying different combinations of changing /  / to /\t/, then checking the sha1 and moving on to the next file when it's correct? That sounds awful, but I'm glad to know there is a way if it should ever come to such a situation. :D

Comment: yep, something like that, this is why you have to be carefull .